# How do you get the text from a selected radio button in a radio button group in Android studio in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

Just been struggling with this. I have all the options for a randomized quiz stored in radio buttons within a radio button group for a quiz. I then want to compare the selected radio button text to the answer I have stored as a variable.

Comment: Just gonna use the if(radioButton.isChecked() && radioButton.text == answer)

Answer (score 0):

radioButton.text == your_string ?

Comment: No, didnt work. Thanks anyways. Think I found a way to do it.